Fourier Series - Proof for Gibbs Phenomenon Theorem
I am currently reading Howell - Principles of Fourier Analysis (2016). On page 176 Howell states
Let $f$ be a periodic, piecewise smooth function with period $p$ and
$$\mathcal{F}[f]|_{t} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_{k}e^{i 2\pi \omega_{k}t}$$
If $f$ has a jump of $j_{0}$ at $t_{0}$, then
$$\lim_{ N \to \infty } \left[ \sum_{k=-N}^N c_{k}e^{i 2 \pi \omega_{k}(t_{0}+t_{{N,m}})}-f(t_{0}+t_{N,m}) \right] = \begin{cases}
 \gamma_{m} j_{0} & \text{ if } m <0 \\
 \gamma_{m} j_{0} & \text{ if } 0 < m
\end{cases}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
 t_{N,m} &= \begin{cases}
 \frac{mp}{2N} &\text{ if } m \text{ is even} \\
 \frac{mp}{2N+2} & \text{ if } m \text{ is odd}
\end{cases} \\[1em]
 \gamma_{m} &= \frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{\pi}\int _{0}^{m\pi} \frac{\sin(\tau)}{\tau} \, d\tau  \\
 j_{0} &= \frac{1}{2}\left[ \lim_{ t \to t_{0}^+ }f(t) + \lim_{ t \to t_{0}^- } f(t) \right]   \\[1em]
 M_{N} &= \begin{cases}
 N-1 & \text{ if } N \text{ is even} \\
 N & \text{ if } N \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$
with $m \in[-M_{N}, M_{N}]\subset \mathbb{Z}$
The author puts this theorem as exercise. To be honest I have no idea where to begin. I know that if $f(t)$ has a jump discontinuity at $t=t_{0}$, then
$$\lim_{ N \to \infty } \sum_{k=-N}^N c_{k}e^{i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t_{0}} = \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\lim_{ \tau \to t_{0}^-}f(\tau) + \lim_{ \tau \to \tau_{0}^+ }f(\tau)  \Bigg]$$
But I don't see a plan on how to show that the Gibbs oscillations will result in the given theorem.
